# Subjunctive vs Gerund

Tags: gerunds, subjunctives, present-subjunctive

> 1. It is necessary that she work on the weekend.
> 2. She working on the weekend is necessary.

I kmow first sentence is subjunctive and second sentence has gerund.

But, Are both sentences correct? If yes, what is the difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The second needs to be

> Her working on the weekend is necessary.

The gerund is the noun and needs a possessive.

And the meaning is pretty much the same.

Comment: It is interesting that the gerunds can also be used with objective pronouns like "I like him being here". What makes it more interesting is the fact that the possessive form and objective form of the third female person is "her" :-)

Comment: Actually, in that case, what you have is a participle modifying the pronoun as an adjective.

Comment: So If “her working” is used,  Are both sentence1 and Sentence2 same?